# Detect primary button of `?` character

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, mousetrap

I'm using Mousetrap to detect the press of <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Actually I'm doing so because I'm interested to the alternative character printed on the <kbd>/</kbd> button (the <kbd>?</kbd>)

If for an user using english keyboard (or any keyboard with <kbd>?</kbd> assigned as secondary action of the <kbd>/</kbd> button) can be simple to understand why I'm asking him to press such key, for an user with a different keyboard (comes to my mind the Italian keyboard where the <kbd>?</kbd> has its own dedicated button) it will be hard to understand why I'm asking him to press such button.

The question then is:

Is there a way to know which button has the `?` symbol on it, and then bind the Mousetrap shortcut to such button?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mousetrap.bind('?', function() { alert('keyboard shortcuts'); });
```

https://craig.is/killing/mice#api.bind.shift

Comment: If I do so, I will need to press `alt+shift+/` on english keyboards, I want to press just `alt+/`